# Got a Facebook error as "Code 200, subcode 2069006" while replying reviews by a page access token at my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

(Solved)
I got an error message as Code 200, subcode 2069006 while using an APP with long-lived page-access-token to reply reviews at my Page. I also have tried the same steps at Graph API Explorer but got the same result. Please see [Graph API Explorer photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo6uE.jpg).
Is this an error only at Graph API v2.10? or do I use any wrong commands? please help me to figure out this issue.

I have asked this question on Facebook Developer Community and search related document on Facebook(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/#Reading), but I can't get any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your app set live yet?

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thank you for your reply on FB. Due to your help, this issue is solved.

Comment: @SnowriverChang how you solve this.. please if you explain. thank's

Comment: And what is the solution?