# Facebook API error 2069006 "User Cannot See This App"

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page on Facebook and app to do some actions on it.

I can get reviews of my page using this API:

> GET 2044933538893604/ratings

And I can get comments of some review.

> GET 2009974472404526/comments

I have problem when I try to add comment to that review post.

> POST 2009974472404526/comments

```
{
    "message" : "some message"
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "error_subcode": `2069006`,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "User Cannot See This App",
    "error_user_msg": "The user who owns object 2,009,974,472,404,526 cannot see this app.",
    "fbtrace_id": "CIrr69/JFp/"
  }
}
```

I have a token that has all permissions enabled.

I see someone had the same problem here [Got a Facebook error as "Code 200, subcode 2069006" while replying reviews by a page access token at my Facebook page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520894/got-a-facebook-error-as-code-200-subcode-2069006-while-replying-reviews-by-a) and looks like he had found a solution but for some reason it is not posted there.

Comment: So basically your app is not live , It's in the development mode so the user who has added review/rating on page  is not able to see your app.
Try to add that user as admin to your app after that you should be able post comment on that particular user's  review//rating.

Comment: It worked when I used another app that is live (published).